# Get substring between two characters

Tags: java, regex

How do you build a regex to return for the characters between `<` and `@` of a string?

For example `<1001@10.2.2.1>` would return 1001.

Would something using `<.?>` work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would something using `"<.?>"` work?

A slightly modified version of it would work: `<.*?@` (you need an `@` at the end, and you need a reluctant quantifier `*?` in place of an optional mark `?`). However it could be inefficient because of [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Something like this would be better:

```
<([^@]*)@
```

This expression starts by finding `<`, taking as many non-`@` characters as it could, and capturing the `@` before stopping.

Parentheses denote a capturing group. Use regex API to extract it:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^@]*)@");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<1001@10.2.2.1>");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This prints `1001` ([demo](http://ideone.com/b0BepS)).

Comment: How do I return the result as a string?

Answer (score 1):

What about the next:

```
(?<=<)[^@]*
```

e.g.:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=<)[^@]*");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<1001@10.2.2.1>";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Um.

```
<([0-9]*?)@
```

I'm assuming it's numbers only.

if all characters use this..

```
<(.*?)@
```

[tested here..](http://www.debuggex.com/)

Maybe i'm lacking knowledge but my understanding of regex is that you need () to get the capture groups... otherwise if you don't you'll just be selecting characters without actually "capturing" them.

so this..

```
<.?>
```

won't do anything .